# SQL Server MERGE multiple on clause variations

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, merge

I am using the MERGE statement to insert/update records in my database.

My source table contains three columns which are used to identify if a record needs inserted or updated. My problem arises in the ON clause – the target table and source table are joined using the three columns however there are numerous variations on how this could be joined. (See below example)

I know the AND / OR operators could be used to achieve this but this will become messy and difficult to maintain. I was wondering if there was a more efficient way?

An example of my code is below:

```
   MERGE Target_Table as t
   USING (select @param1, @param2, @param3)       
      AS s (col1, col2, col3)
      ON (t.col1 = s.col1
     AND t.col2 = s.col2
     AND t.col3 = s.col3)
      OR (t.col1 = s.col2
     AND t.col2 = s.col1
     AND t.col3 = s.col3)
    WHEN
 MATCHED
    THEN […update…]
    WHEN
     NOT
 MATCHED
    THEN […insert…]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hard to tell  based on what you listed for me. Can any column match any other column in the other table? Readability is almost as important as performance IMHO. And though i'm sure you are aware, since you are using multiple AND / OR operators, be careful to remember SQL Server's precedence in evaluating these. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Yes, the three variables I am using in the source table can match any of the three columns in the target table in any order. Additionally I have limited the example to three variables however there can be up to six. I would like to see if there is a nicer way to evaluate the data and see if the variables are found within any of the columns

Comment: Are all of the params unique or can those values equal eachother? For example, can param1 and param2 both be "1"?

Answer (score 0):

You could build up the source table differently, so rather than using `OR` you could build up the combinations before the merge condition. e.g.

```
DECLARE @param1 INT = 1, 
        @param2 INT = 2, 
        @param3 INT = 3;   


WITH Params AS
(   SELECT  pValue, pNumber
    FROM    (VALUES (@param1, 1), (@param2, 2), (@param3, 3)) p (pValue, pNumber)
)
SELECT  Col1 = p1.Pvalue, Col2 = p2.Pvalue, Col3 = p3.Pvalue
FROM    Params AS P1
        INNER JOIN Params AS p2
            ON p2.pNumber NOT IN (p1.pNumber)
        INNER JOIN Params AS p3
            ON p3.pNumber NOT IN (p1.pNumber, p2.pNumber);
```

This gives you your 6 combinations (with each join making sure you are not re-using the same parameter):

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
------------------
2       3       1
3       2       1
1       3       2
3       1       2
1       2       3
2       1       3
```

So your `MERGE` condition become much simpler:

```
WITH Params AS
(   SELECT  pValue, pNumber
    FROM    (VALUES (@param1, 1), (@param2, 2), (@param3, 3)) p (pValue, pNumber)
), SourceTable AS
(   SELECT  Col1 = p1.Pvalue, Col2 = p2.Pvalue, Col3 = p3.Pvalue
    FROM    Params AS P1
            INNER JOIN Params AS p2
                ON p2.pNumber NOT IN (p1.pNumber)
            INNER JOIN Params AS p3
                ON p3.pNumber NOT IN (p1.pNumber, p2.pNumber)
)
MERGE Target_Table AS t
USING SourceTable AS s
    ON t.col1 = s.col1
    AND t.col2 = s.col2
    AND t.col3 = s.col3
WHEN MATCHED THEN […update…]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN […insert…];
```

This also makes it easier to add further parameters, so a 4th parameter would only require an extra row in the CTE `params`, rather than a whole new set of `OR` conditions

```
DECLARE @param1 INT = 1, 
        @param2 INT = 2, 
        @param3 INT = 3, 
        @param4 INT = 4;   


WITH Params AS
(   SELECT  pValue, pNumber
    FROM    (VALUES (@param1, 1), (@param2, 2), (@param3, 3), (@Param4, 4)) p (pValue, pNumber)
)
SELECT  Col1 = p1.Pvalue, Col2 = p2.Pvalue, Col3 = p3.Pvalue
FROM    Params AS P1
        INNER JOIN Params AS p2
            ON p2.pNumber NOT IN (p1.pNumber)
        INNER JOIN Params AS p3
            ON p3.pNumber NOT IN (p1.pNumber, p2.pNumber);
```

Which then gives all 24 combinations, without much extra code.